# Condition aura:if with custom field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

i am want to use dynamic changing of the button. I am using aura:if but i dont know how to pass custom field value into it, or if it is even possible.

```
                <aura:if isTrue="{!customField__c == 0}">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:copy"  onclick="{!c.copyOrDelete}" />
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:copy"  onclick="{!c.copyOrDelete}" />
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
```

I am using checkbox custom field to get boolean as i need to, in the custom object.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can pass aura attribute into isTrue expression. How do you define this `customField__c` in your component code?

Comment: I dont. I dont know how to do it. Its something with <aura:attribute />?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting `customField__c`? Assuming you have something in lines of:

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="SObject"/>
```

in your markup and you are setting a value to that record attribute from your ControllerJS like so:

```
component.set("v.record", response.getReturnValue()); //assuming a server-side action here that returns customField__c in its query
```

then you can do something like:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.record.customField__c == 0}">
                    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:copy"  onclick="{!c.copyOrDelete}" />
                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:copy"  onclick="{!c.copyOrDelete}" />
                    </aura:set>
                </aura:if>
```

Notice the `{!v.record.customField__c == 0}` syntax. The 'value provider', identified by `{!v.XXX}` is required at all times when referring to an attribute.

So in short, you are missing the value provider in your condition:

```
{!customField__c == 0}
```